# How to display a checkbox field using ligntning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, datatable, checkbox

I'm trying to display a check box field using lightning:datatable component.

Here is the component markup.

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="invoices" type="Invoice__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>

<lightning:datatable data="{! v.invoices }" columns="{! v.columns }" keyField="id"/>
```

And this is my init controller method

```
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.columns",[
        {label:"Invoice Number", fieldName:"Name",type:"text"},
        {label:"Date", fieldName:"Date__c",type:"date"},
        {label:"Amount", fieldName:"Amount__c",type:"currency"},
         {label:"Paid", fieldName:"Paid__c",type:"text"}
    ]);

    var action = component.get("c.getInvoices");
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        component.set("v.invoices",response.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); }
```

This is the output.

[image: datatable output]

All data is populated on the table except **Paid__c**, which is a checkbox. How do you display a checkbox field in a datatable? I have tried changing the type to boolean and checkbox without any luck. The documentation for neither lightning:datatable nor lightning:formattedText talks about displaying checkbox fields.

Comment: I think currently datatable does not support checkboxes (It supports buttons). Please read more about datatables  [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) particularly **Formatting with Data Types** Section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Old:** Out of the box `<lighting:datatable>` component doesn't support booleans as checkboxes in the standard data types, the supported data types currently are:

- action
- button
- currency
- date
- email
- location
- number
- percent
- phone
- text
- url

These can be found under the "Formatting with Data Types" section on the [Lightning datatables reference documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm)

A quick workaround to this would be to output a text formula of the `Paid__c` field to display Yes / No or Paid / Unpaid and then to output this in the column.

Other than this you may need to look into more flexible table options which would allow for the use / display of checkbox fields.

**Edit:** From API Version 42 onwards the Boolean type is now supported.

Comment: Note: starting with API 42 there is a `type: 'boolean'` support

Answer (score 7):

Checkbox columns are now supported out-of-the-box in [`lightning:datatable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) and doesn't require custom Javascripting.

> **`boolean:`**    Displays the icon utility:check if the value is true, and a blank value otherwise.

**Example**

```
component.set('v.columns', [
    {label:"Invoice Number", fieldName:"Name",type:"text"},
    {label:"Date", fieldName:"Date__c",type:"date"},
    {label:"Amount", fieldName:"Amount__c",type:"currency"},
    {label:"Paid", fieldName:"Paid__c",type:"boolean"}                
]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `iconName` cell attribute to display icons in your datatable (see the "Appending an Icon to Column Data" section in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm)).

This can either be a static value, e.g. `utility:user` if you want the same icon to be displayed in all rows. But (and this is what you'd need in your case) it can also take a field name which holds the name of the icon to display.

And so your Paid column would look something like:

```
{label: "Paid", fieldName: "Paid__c", type: "text", cellAttributes: {
    iconName: { fieldName: 'paidIcon' }
}}
```

Where your client-side logic would populate the `paidIcon` field with either `utility:check` or `null` based on the boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use checkbox unicodes by replacing true an false values with them.

```
columns = [
    { label: 'label1', fieldName: 'col1ApiName',cellAttributes: { class: 'slds-text-heading_medium' }},
    { label: 'label2', fieldName: 'col2ApiName',cellAttributes: { class: 'slds-text-heading_medium' }},
];

//Sample data
data = [
    {"Id": 1234, "col1ApiName": true, "col2ApiName": false},
    {"Id": 1234, "col1ApiName": false, "col2ApiName": true},
];

data.forEach(function(record){   
    let booleanColumns = ['col1ApiName', 'col2ApiName'];
    booleanColumns.forEach(x=>{
                                record[x] = record[x] == false ? '\u2610' : '\u2611';
                            })
});
```