# Why does a checkmark not appear on a boolean column in a lightning:datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a very simple Lightning Web Component that uses a `lightning-datatable` to display a list view of data.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Leads" icon-name="standard:client">
        <lightning-datatable data={leads.data}
                             columns={columns}
                             key-field="Id"
                             onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                             hide-checkbox-column>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

One of the columns is a checkbox field, so I'm trying to make that column boolean so that it will show up as a checkmark in the list.

```
columns = [
    {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text', sortable: 'true'},
    {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status__c', type: 'text', sortable: 'true',
        fixedWidth: 100},
    {label: 'NAP Confirmed', fieldName: 'NAP_Confirmed__c', type: 'boolean',
        sortable: 'true', fixedWidth: 125},
    {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone__c', type: 'phone', sortable: 'true'},
    {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email__c', type: 'email', sortable: 'true'},
    {label: 'Source', fieldName: 'Source__c', type: 'text', sortable: 'true'},
    {label: 'Date', fieldName: 'Date__c', type: 'date', sortable: 'true'},
    {type: "action", typeAttributes: { rowActions: this.actions,
                                       menuAlignment: "auto" }}
];
```

But no checkmark appears when the value in `NAP_Confirmed__C` is check elsewhere in the system.

Here's the rendering o my datatable:

[image]

And here's the detail view of the record with that field checked:

[image]

How do I get that column to show a checkmark (or a checkbox if I want to make it editable) on that column?

Comment: See this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209335/how-to-display-a-checkbox-field-using-ligntningdatatable. Is it possible that the API version on your component is below 42?

Comment: @MenachemShanowitz, I'm afraid not. the metadata file specifies a version of 51.0.

Comment: can you give a sample of what the return data looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embarrassing to admit, but I had neglected to retrieve the `NAP_Confirmed__c` field in the SOQL query in the Apex controller. Once I did that it worked perfectly.